# Do all Lie groups admit deformation retracts onto compact subgroups?

Tags: lie-groups

The noncompact Lie group $SL(n, \mathbb{R})$ admits a deformation retract onto the compact Lie group $SO(n, \mathbb{R})$ via polar decomposition. Do all noncompact Lie groups admit deformation retracts onto compact subgroups? (This is motivated by [Is this a valid way to show $\chi(SL_n(\mathbb{R}))=0$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/939810/is-this-a-valid-way-to-show-chisl-n-mathbbr-0/939822) , where one solution uses the existence of the aforementioned retract.)

Comment: IIRC an even stronger statement is true, namely that every connected Lie group is diffeomorphic to the product of a maximal compact subgroup and some $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan  is isomorphic?  Does this result gives  us  an alternative proof  for the following:http://mathoverflow.net/questions/247935/the-pair-gln-mathbbr-on-as-a-groupoid  ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Qiaochu Yuan's comment sent me in the right direction:

1. The theorem he gives is correct as stated, and is due to Cartan: Any connected Lie group is diffeomorphic to the product of a maximal compact subgroup and $\mathbb{R}^n$ for some $n$ (and in fact all maximal compact subgroups are conjugate). There's some good discussion of proofs of this fact on Math Overflow: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/53080/homotopy-type-of-connected-lie-groups . Mostow gives a compact argument in this 1949 Bulletin AMS article: http://www.ams.org/journals/bull/1949-55-10/S0002-9904-1949-09325-4/home.html .
2. Something better yet is true in the semisimple case: Any semisimple Lie group $G$ admits a so-called Iwasawa decomposition
   $$G := KAN$$ into Lie groups, where

   - $K$ is the maximal compact subgroup,
   - $A$ is abelian, and
   - $N$ is nilpotent.
     In particular, the factors $A$ and $N$ are contractible, so $K$ is a deformation retract of $G$. In the case of the given example, $G = SL(n, \mathbb{R})$, $K = SO(n, \mathbb{R})$, $A$ is the group of positive diagonal $n \times n$ matrices, and $N$ is the group of upper triangular matrices with diagonal elements all $1$.

Comment: you don't need G to be semisimple for the Iwasawa decomposition?

Comment: You're right, thanks @Timkinsella. In fact, the Iwasawa decomposition can be used in the proof of the general case, it seems.